# Using a CASE WHEN with multiple Whens that is only resulting in a BOOLEAN value

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I am working on writing a SQL Query which is using a CASE line with multiple When's, and I was wondering why my result is only showing BOOLEAN (True/False) Values. Ideally I would like it to show whatever is after the THEN's in my code.

```
--with loan as (
SELECT DISTINCT
rtw.identifierdimsk
,lmmf.milestonesk
,lmd.groupname
,rtw.typecode
,rtw.campaignname
,rtw.partnername
,rtw.sourcename
,lmmf.date
,rtw.typecode = CASE WHEN rtw.typecode = 'PROS' THEN 'Prospect'
               WHEN rtw.typecode = 'CARI' THEN  'Deluxe'
               WHEN rtw.typecode = ('CARIC') OR rtw.typecode = ('CTE') THEN  'CSignal'
               WHEN rtw.typecode = 'RMT' THEN  'Pre Pull'
               WHEN rtw.typecode in ('90','90PLUS','C90','C90PLUS','BP','ELO','AUTO','POP') THEN  'In-process'
               WHEN rtw.typecode = 'XU3%' THEN  'U3'
               WHEN rtw.typecode = '%CT%' THEN 'Misc'
               END AS Value
FROM rtal_winner rtw
INNER JOIN one_fact lmmf ON lmmf.identifierdimsk = rtw.identifierdimsk
INNER JOIN one_dim lmd ON lmd.milestonesk = lmmf.milestonesk
AND lmmf.date >= '2022-10-25'
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are comparing `rtw.typecode` to the result of the `case` expression:

```sql
rtw.typecode = CASE ...
```

remove the comparison part:

```sql
, lmmf.date
, CASE 
    WHEN rtw.typecode = 'PROS' THEN 'Prospect'
    -- ...
  END AS Value
FROM rtal_winner rtw
```

Comment: Guru I need one help from you, can I have your email id? Or other way to connect with you?

Comment: +1 to this answer - you are asking the SQL compiler to return whether the value of rtw.typecode is equal to the result of the case statement when what you actually want is just the result of the case statement.